# Получение програмной части-ядра из файла .rom

Tags: ассемблер

Имееться прошивка контроллера(example.rom), в которой находяться ресурсы+ программная часть, подскажите как получить программную часть? (Если можно посоветуйте, что почитать по реверсу прошивок.. )

Comment: binwalk уже пробовали?

Comment: неа, посмотрю щас

Comment: Binwalk выдает :1009758 0xF685E Cisco IOS experimental microcode, for ""
1925488 0x1D6170 EBML file

Comment: Это похоже на правду вообще? :-)

Comment: не, файл был xorм обработан